# Franck Hertz experiment and the Mean Free Path

Tags: quantum-mechanics, experimental-physics, mean-free-path

As part of my project in physics, I tried to repeat the franck hertz experiment, I did the same experiment with Neon and Mercury (the lengh between the catode and lattice is $5 mm$), I measured the free mean path of the electrons in both cases and I got the result that MFP in the neon is about $0.005 mm$ and the MFP in the Mercury is about $0.640 mm$. I understood so far that I can conclude that this because the fact that the atoms of the neon is much bigger than the mercury (thats the main difference betweel the volume of liquid and gas). Am I correct in my assumption? what else can I infer?

Comment: (a) Neon atoms are much smaller than mercury atoms. Consult a table of atomic radii. (b) Electrons in gases isn't my field at all, but I'm sure that anyone looking at your question would want to know how you *measured* these mean free paths that you give.

Comment: @PhilipWood I just used this calculator by plugging the correct numbers https://www.omnicalculator.com/physics/mean-free-path

Comment: @Sangigever So you didn't actually *measure* the mean free path, but calculated theoretical values from data such as gas pressure and atomic diameter?

Comment: the theoretical values is according to my measurements

Comment: @can I infer that the neon has better conductivty? since there is less collisions of electrons wich means "more" electrons hit the lattice and than the anode?

Comment: (a) I'm sorry but I don't understand your inference. (b) There is no lattice in a gas or vapour (c) Didn't you make any electrical measurements (pd and anode current)?